# Python Pandas Left Merge works part of the time?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am running into an issue when I merge two dataframes (one containing hundreds of rows, the other contains just five rows).

```
data_df = pd.merge(data_df, info_df, how='left', on=['Identification'])
```

Info_df contains information that I need to match up to the data_df where the ID's match up. The data_df contains hundreds of rows but all of their ID's are within the five ID's held in the info_df.

My issue comes when I do the merge, my 330 lines of rows in the data_df after the left join only returns 312 rows of data to the new data_df despite the ID existing in the info_df and working for other records that have that ID.

I do not know if this is a consistency issue with pandas or if I am doing something wrong but some help would really go a long way.

Please let me know if more information is required and thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you edit into your post a few lines from these DataFrames that reproduce the issue?

Comment: I cannot because it contains data that I would rather not share. I just really need to know if this is a problem that is in my environment only or if others have had similar issues when working with large data files using pandas.

Comment: Gotcha. I have not seen this behaviour myself: the first thing I would check is the possibility that some rows in `data_df` have values that look identical or similar to a human, but are different due to special characters or trailing spaces.